# Segmentation fault on Cuda

Tags: c++, c, cuda, gpu

I'm writing CUDA program to processing images. I got segmentation fault problem and I’ve no completely no idea why. I'm probably just miss some minor thing, but after hours of trying to correct myself I couldn’t make it running.
I'm setting correct grid,block and shred memory values( at least I think so), according to deviceQuery on my hardware(GeForce310M total shmem:16384,max threads per block:512 and max block dim 521).
Here is output I get before segmentation fault:

```
Cols and Rows:
256
384
total:98304 // rows*cols
Block Size:512
Grid Size:192
shared mem:2048
```

Below is the kernel code

```
__global__ void reduce_min(float *minVar,float* d_logLuminance)
{
    extern __shared__ float s_data[];   //shared memeory
    unsigned int tId = threadIdx.x;
    unsigned int global_id = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + tId;

    //Copy to shared mem
    s_data[tId] = d_logLuminance[global_id];
    __syncthreads();

    for(unsigned int i = 1;i<blockDim.x;i*=2)
    {
        if(tId%(2*i) == 0)
        {
            s_data[tId] = min(s_data[tId],s_data[tId+i]);   
        }
        __syncthreads();
    }
    if(tId == 0)
        d_logLuminance[blockIdx.x] = s_data[0];
}
```

And the part where I allocate memory and invoke kernel

```
size_t size = 512;
    size_t sizeOfgrid = (numRows*numCols)/size;
    const dim3 blockSize(size,1,1); 
    const dim3 gridSize(sizeOfgrid,1,1);
    unsigned int sharedMem =(sizeof(float)*size); //Shared memory per block

    printf("%s\n%d\n%d\n%s%d\n","Cols and Rows:",numCols,numRows,"total:",numRows*numCols);
    printf("%s%d\n%s%d\n%s%d\n","Block Size:",size,"Grid Size:",sizeOfgrid,"shared mem:",sharedMem);

    float* d_lum;
    float* outData;
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&d_lum,sizeof(float)*numRows*numCols));
        checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(d_lum,d_logLuminance,sizeof(float)*numRows*numCols,cudaMemcpyDeviceToDevice));   
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMalloc(&outData,sizeof(float)*numRows*numCols));

    reduce_min<<<gridSize,blockSize,sharedMem>>>(outData,d_lum);
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    checkCudaErrors(cudaGetLastError());        
    checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(&min_logLum,outData,sizeof(float)*numRows*numCols,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
```

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: A segmentation fault *always* comes from host code. You kernel cannot cause a segfault on the host. Surely you can generate a trace in your host code to work out where it is coming from?

Comment: Oh my.. I found out where I set wrong memory size to copy. Now program finishes work, but i now got _nan_ instead of value...

Comment: If you have found the answer to this question yourself, please add it as an answer. Later on you will be able to accept your own answer and get this off the unanswered question list.

Answer (score 1):

```
checkCudaErrors(cudaMemcpy(&min_logLum,outData,sizeof(float)*numRows*numCols,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
```

This function was generating an segmentation fault, because I forgot to mention (and I missed it when I was writing code) that `min_logLum` is a `float`, not a `float*` of size `numRows*numCols`. So in the end I was trying to copy much more memory than I had allocated.